# Hive adapters and boxes with Get_it how should i regester them into getit

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-pub, service-locator, get-it

I have always issues with hive boxies instances and the error of not initilizing the box or adapter
so I decided to register them in one place and use it all over place .but I don't event know how to use and register adapters and box

I have nothing tried because I don't know how to implement that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recommended place to register an adapter using `Hive.registerAdapter()` is immediately after the `Hive.initFlutter()` finishes, then open your box with the object type that you made the adapter for, like this:

```
Future<void> main() async {
  await Hive.initFlutter();
  Hive.registerAdapter<Question>(QuestionAdapter());
  await Hive.openBox<Question>("questions");

  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

now the "questions" box will be available to use directly across your whole app by :

```
Hive.box("questions");
```